# Nuxt 3 + Electron no possible configuration to enable SSR

Tags: electron, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

I am working on a project (just for my own interest) to make a `faster searching file explorer`. I am used to making my web-projects in Nuxt, so I wanted to try if I could combine `electron with Nuxt` to make a nice simple application.

For this project, I need to do some server side rendering (getting directories and drives from the users computer). I do this by using the `integrated server api routes` from nuxt. This basically works the same as a rest api, so i can just fetch from my frontend to that route.

Works verry nice in development mode in the browser! But when I want to fetch the directories from the server side api, the functionality does not work because it cannot host the server-side.
Electron also `relies on the 'nuxt generate'` command, because electron needs an index.html. When trying to use `'nuxt build'` instead, `it does not create the required index.html anymore`.

Any one knows a solution so this still works? You can play around at [my github repository.](https://github.com/ericvdberge/Portfolio-FastExplorer)
To run the functionality in the browser, use the startup command `yarn dev`, and to run it using electron, use `yarn generate`, then use `yarn start` to run the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried multiple approaches, and after a couple of days I got it to work.

1. My first approach, was to use `import { fork, spawn } from 'child_process'` (one of the fork or spawn methods from child_process) to spin up the server that allows SSR by running `nuxt build` (which generates `.output/server/index.mjs`) and run it using:

   ```js
   fork(path.join(process.env.ROOT, '.output/server/index.mjs'))
   ```

   This worked great when running `electron .` in my package.json as a command, because it did spin up the server, and by using `window.loadURL('http://localhost:3000')` (instead of the index.html), the SSR was **working and the frontend page was loaded**.
   **But** the problem was that fork or spawn from child_process are not working after packaging the app using electron-builder. This is because the environment does not contain node anymore after building the package in an app.
2. My second approach (after trying to make approach 1 work for 2 days) was to use `const { pathToFileURL } = require('url')` to load the module and to call the script in the main.js electron file. This is done by dynamically importing the script and running it by using:

   ```js
   const modulePath = path.join(process.env.ROOT, '.output/server/index.mjs');
   const moduleUrl = pathToFileURL(modulePath).href;
   const { default: startServer } = await import(moduleUrl);

   if (typeof startServer === 'function') {
       startServer();
   }
   ```

   **This method works in development mode, but also after packaging the application using electron-builder!**. The only added configuration that you need to do is including the following text in your package.json:

   ```json
   "build": {
       "extraResources": [
           ".output/server/**"
       ]
   }
   ```

**Conclusion**: make sure you use the second approach to make SSR work with Nuxt 3 and Electron. Do not forget to run the server script first, and then create the window, so make for example a function called startWebServer and a function called createWindow to run this code:

```js
app.whenReady()
  .then(startWebServer)
  .then(createWindow)
```